# html entities to characters through http header

Tags: php, http-headers, html-entities

Is there any way to convert html entities into characters without using any entity decoder function like html_entity_decode, I mean by setting up http headers?

Requirement: I have a web page that is being redirected to another new web page with some parameters. Param value contains some html characters like " to be shown on page but it is showing as " instead of ". I do not want to use html_entity_decode on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for:

```
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
```

that will solve the problem

Comment: No, this is not solving my problem. I am already using urlencode, urldecode. I'm encoding url before redirecting to second page on the second page it getting decoded.